# How to implement batch publish in kafka and don't lose data

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I'm using kafkajs nodejs library, which doesn't fully implement a batch publish, and from my side I see only one way - is implement it by myself, but I don't fully understand how to do it, so I have some questions

1. How should I calculate message size to implement `batch.size` property?
2. If application is gracefully shutdown, then I can just force publish messages from the producer buffer in the shutdown hooks, is it right?
3. If application was killed by `sigkill` signal, how I should avoid messages lost?

Comment: Look into the Outbox Pattern